# virt-rescue for Ubuntu

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I want to install [virt-rescue](http://libguestfs.org/virt-rescue.1.html) on Ubuntu 11.10 or Ubuntu 10.04. It could not be found in the repositories. Where can I get it?